# Printing UTF-8 empty set

Tags: utf-8, sml, smlnj, windows-console

This might be a Windows-centric problem. In any event, I decided to play around with [Von-Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals) in SML. This is an encoding of the natural numbers in which each number is represented by a pure set -- a set whose elements are themselves sets.

I wrote the following code:

```
datatype set = EMPTY | SET of set list;

fun succ EMPTY = SET [EMPTY]
|   succ (SET sets) = SET (sets @ [SET sets]);

fun ordinal 0 = EMPTY
|   ordinal n = succ (ordinal (n-1));

fun pprint S e = 
    let
        fun f EMPTY = e
        |   f (SET sets) = "{" ^ (String.concatWith "," (map f sets)) ^ "}"
    in
        f S
    end;

fun display n e = print ( "\n" ^ (pprint (ordinal n) e ) ^ "\n\n");
```

The display function takes a natural number and a string representation of the empty set. For example:

```
- display 3 "O";

{O,{O},{O,{O}}}

val it = () : unit
```

(which meshes with the Wikipedia entry on Von Neumann Ordinals). As a flourish I wanted to use an ["O" with a stroke through it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98#Computers), so I did the following:

```
- display 3 "\195\152";

{Ø,{Ø},{Ø,{Ø}}}

}}

val it = () : unit
```

(You need to run `chcp 65001` at the Window's command prompt before starting SML to get this to work).

There is a phantom line break in the middle of the string as well as an extra "}". I have no idea why. I've tried with other values of `n` and sometimes get phantom boxes in the middle of the line and always an extra "}". I've tried various work-arounds (short of ditching Windows for Linux) with no success.

Does anyone know a reliable way to print the empty set using a stroke through an "O" in SML?

Comment: In Danish, the uppercase letter Ø is present in [ISO-8859 (Latin-1)](http://www.iangraham.org/books/xhtml1/entity/en_test.html) as an 8-bit encoding.

Comment: Just FYI, it displays just fine on my OS X.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan Must be a glitch either in how Window's command prompt handles Unicode or perhaps with how SML/NJ passes the '\xxx' characters to Windows. Odd.